# Which model to use when mixed-effects, random-effects added regression is needed

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, mixed-models

So mixed-effects regression model is used when I believe that there is dependency with a particular group of a feature. I've attached the Wiki link because it explains better than me. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model)

Although I believe that there are many occasions in which we need to consider the mixed-effects, there aren't too many modules that support this.
R has lme4 and Python seems to have a similar module, but they are both statistic driven; they do not use the cost function algorithm such as gradient boosting.

In Machine Learning setting, how would you handle the situation that you need to consider mixed-effects? Are there any other models that can handle longitudinal data with mixed-effects(random-effects)?

(R seems to have a package that supports mixed-effects: https://rd.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-011-5258-3
But I am looking for a Python solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are, at least, two ways to handle longitudinal data with mixed-effects in Python:

1. [StatsModel](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/mixed_linear.html) for linear mixed effects;
2. [MERF](https://github.com/manifoldai/merf) for mixed effects random forest.

If you go for StatsModel, I'd recommend you to do some of the examples provided [here](https://github.com/kshedden/Statsmodels-MixedLM). If you go for MERF, I'd say that the best starting point is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/mixed-effects-random-forests-6ecbb85cb177).

I hope it helps!